# assembly is not compatible with the 64-bit processor architecture used by IIS on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I am getting a warning message when I try to run my asp.net application on my devmachine appfabric .and I am getting error [message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsgeneral/thread/d94e1c46-1e9b-45c3-8b37-b2ac15e0b3bc) when I upload my application to azure cloud

> project contains the following assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll. This assembly is not compatible with the 64-bit processor architecture used by IIS on Windows Azure. To make sure that the role starts, you must replace this assembly with one that is compatible with this architecture."

Where I can get an azure compatible dll ?

Comment: What do you have installed?  VS, TFS or the Team Explorer?

Comment: Try changing your project properties to "any CPU" and this will help you to use mix mode assemblies in your project.

Comment: I tried that,but no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [run your application pool in **32-bit mode**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx). Try running this [`appcmd`](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) (*you can do this [automatically using role startup task](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/17/using-startup-task-in-windows-azure-detailed-summary.aspx)*) to assign the default application pool settings to enable 32-bit support.

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config  -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:"True"  /commit:apphost

Comment: This isn't necessarily _the_answer_ as what if you have an x64bit application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I set Build | Platform Target to Any CPU (previously some of them had been X86).
This fixed the issue for me.