# Windows Azure: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache'

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm trying to debug a **ASP MVC** application in the **Windows Azure** Compute emulator and I'm getting the following error before the application starts. My configuration is the following:

- Windows 8 x64
- Windows **Azure Compute emulator** (debugging local)
- **IIS express** (this is important since the error is thrown by this process)

I have read [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643654/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-teamfoundation-workitemtracking-clien) [other](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/4e9ae9b6-7070-448a-862d-a7b3292e58c1/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o) and some other [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631849/assembly-is-not-compatible-with-the-64-bit-processor-architecture-used-by-iis-on), and the problem seems to be a **x68/x64** compatibility problem.

The solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643654/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-teamfoundation-workitemtracking-clien) post is configure IIS to allow 32 bits applications, but I don't know how to configure IIS Express to do it.

Here is the detailed error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
 Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = TITANIUM\Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/workspace2/01nerva/src/client/webui/Codice.Web.Client/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\workspace2\01nerva\src\client\webui\Codice.Web.Client\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\workspace2\01nerva\src\client\webui\Codice.Web.Client\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cf250a6c/39ae37b/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cf250a6c/39ae37b/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/workspace2/01nerva/src/client/webui/Codice.Web.Client/bin/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Stack Trace: 

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12759734
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +503
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +203
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12880068
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12721257
```

Comment: Do you have `CopyLocal=true` for the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache` assembly? Also, I believe the Azure emulator uses full IIS, not IIS Express.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Cache' or one of its dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643654/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-teamfoundation-workitemtracking-clien)